# How to reduce the vertical space above and below a ul list uniformly with one command?

Tags: theme-development, css

> **PROBLEM:** How to reduce the vertical space above and below a ul list without having to define different classes according to the objects before and after the list? That is, is it possibile to reduce the space of a fixed quantity using only one class regardless of the objects above and below the list?

This is the default vertical spacing in a wordpress list (code on left, output on right)

[image]

I think that the spacing is too much, so I would like to reduce it and I find out that I have to modify the top and bottom `margin` of the `ul` list. I experimented a bit and I think the default values for spacing are `1em` top and bottom. The strange thing is that when decreasing from `1em` to `0em` nothing happens, so I had to go negative and find out that a good value is `-0.5em`

[image]

Then I tried the same but with `div` instead of text

[image]

This time the vertical space already changes when decreasing from `1em` to `0em`, so to decrease as much as in the previous case, I had to set a value of `0.5em`. By futher decreasing to `-0.5em` the vertical spacing is reduced too much.

[image]

So in the case of a `div` before the list and text after the list (and viceversa), two different `margin` values have to be set in order to have equal spacing above and below

[image]

And maybe there are other types of objects which needs different `margin` values.

I was hoping I could set globablly the vertical spacing of the list, without having to define different classes and manually set the correct class each time I have to use a list.

Am I doing something wrong or is this how the job has to be done? Isn't there a way to set globally the space and don't have to worry every time a list has to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens when decreasing from `1em` to `0em` because the text above and below the list is inserted in `p` tags by `wpautop` function, and in my stylesheet I had set `p { margin: 1em 0; }` hence there is a `1em` space which overlapps.

The problem is solved globally using the `+` adjacent sibling selector (read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp))

```
div + ul { margin-top: 0.5em; }
ul + div { margin-top: -0.5em; }
p + ul { margin-top: -0.5em; }
ul + p { margin-top: -0.5em; }
```